# `on('notification')` is not triggered on iOS when app is not running

Tags: ios, ionic3, phonegap-plugin-push

I'm using the `phonegap-plugin-push` on my ionic3 app and I've been facing this issue with the iOS platform (android is ok). When the app is in background/foreground everything works as expected. When the app is not running however, I get the message on the notification tray but neither tapping the notification or the app icon triggers the `on('notification')` event, it simply runs and ignore the incoming notification.

I'm using the `{ ... content-available: 1}` in the aps json message as suggested by the docs, but it doesn't seem to have any effect (though, it does have effect on Android), the ionic app itself never gets the message even though the device received it and displayed it on the tray.

Bellow, I show my configurations and a sample message sent to the push services. If anyone have any idea on how to sort this out will be appreciated, I've tested on ios 8.x and ios 11.x, both have presented the same behavior.

```
const options: PushOptions = {
    android: {
        senderID: '*************',
        icon: 'ic_stat_ic_notification'
    },
    ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: 'true',
        sound: 'true'
    },
    windows: {}
};

platform.ready().then(() => {
    push.on('registration').subscribe((data: EventResponse) => {
        // register data.registrationId
    });

    push.on('notification').subscribe((data: EventResponse) => {
        alert(data.message)
    });
});
```

Sample message:

```
{
    "aps": {
      "alert": "This is a Push",
      "badge": 1,
      "content-available": 1
    },
    "payload": {
      "type": "news"
    }
}
```

Comment: _it simply runs and ignore the incoming notification_ What runs? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long of a comment. It's more of an indirect answer.

1) *or the app icon triggers the on('notification') event* <-- that's expected. Imagine your app just received 10 notifications. How should it know which notification you intended to open?

2) *neither tapping the notification* <-- this should trigger something in your code. Do you have [`didReceiveNotificationResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter?language=objc) implemented? Does that get called? Or does your didFinishLaunching get launched with a [`remoteNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey/1622967-remotenotification) key? How about your `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` does that get called?

Comment: I guess you're right. It's a cordova plugin, and yes, it does implements the method you stated. The plugin docs says the `content-available: 1` on the aps message wakes up the app to register the notification (I guess the notification stays in memory until you run the app). However, I coudn't simulate the scenario where the app is ran from tapping the app icon (all the others possible cases are ok). It seem to be an issue with the plugin because I'm using a version that supports ios 8, but, as ios 8 usage shrinks, they've dropped support for ios 8 and therefore it probably has some issues.

Comment: As it doens't worth a fix on the plugin, I'm changing the way the app consumes notifications to use a more reliable source of persistence and use the push as a trigger only. But your points were useful, because [of what is told on phonegap-plugin-push docs] I assumed  the app was going to wake and store the notification and send it to Ionic through cordova as the app is ran, however it deson't seem to function this way.

Comment: @Honey:sir i am facing same issue can you help me regarding above issue?

Comment: @Kapilsoni what is your problem? Can you be specific?

Comment: @honey- onNotification function is not fire if app is in foreground.in background if I tap any notification in such case it's not fire but in android everything working fine.this is my issue sir can you help me how to fix it?